# visualizing geoRSS on a globe

Tags: data-visualization, georss

What are my options if I'd like to display GeoRSS data on a globe like the one found [here](http://www.geocodearth.com).

Answer (score 0):

Using Openlayers,
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/georss.html

or  google maps api,
http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/03/kml-and-georss-support-added-to-google.html

or Yahoo Maps :
developer dot yahoo dot com slash maps slash georss
(I have a two link limit)